# Python 3.4: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am currently writing a program to pull a list of strings from the first column of a csv file, then store it in a .txt file, and finally use urllib to parse Yahoo Finance for the price that corresponds to each. However i keep on getting the error:

`TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface.`

Here is my code thus far:

```
import csv
import urllib.request

completeList = open('complete.txt', 'r+')

def ReadNasdaq():
    with open('NASDAQ_companylist.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for column in spamreader:
            completeList.write(column[0]+'\n')
            print(column[0]," - ",column[1])

ReadNasdaq()

def ParsePrice():
    for line in completeList:
        yahooFinance = urllib.request.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+line).read()
        price = yahooFinance.split('<span id="yfs_l84_'+line.lower()+'">' )[1].split("</span>")[0]
        print(line, " - ", price)   

ParsePrice()
```

The error is on the line:

```
price = yahooFinance.split('<span id="yfs_l84_'+line.lower()+'">' )[1].split("</span>")[0]
```

I know I have to convert the string into Unicode or binary, but any idea how I could do so?

Comment: Which line? Please post the whole stacktrace

Comment: As Martijn pointed out, if you are doing any complicated HTML handling, you want to use a library for that, like BeautifulSoup or lxml.

Answer (score 0):

Something is expecting byte strings but you give in Unicode strings.

In this case you are trying to split the binary data you get back from the read() with a Unicode string.

Try this:

```
price = yahooFinance.split(b'<span id="yfs_l84_'+line.lower()+b'">' )[1].split(b"</span>")[0]
```

Comment: `byte.split()` more likely.

Comment: Or they can try and decode the HTTP response first.. There's `response.info().get_param('charset')` to see if the server included a hint. Or they should stop hacking HTML by hand and start using BeautifulSoup, which will auto-detect the codec.

Comment: Yeah, depends on what they want to do with it.